# Difference between using homebrew and npm to install libraries

Tags: macos, npm, homebrew

I am wondering about the difference between installing let's say PhantomJS via Homebrew and NPM. Homebrew installs the library under /usr/local/bin and NPM installs phabtomJS under ~/.npm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this specific library, but the general policy of Homebrew is to rely on existing packaging systems such as npm, gem, pip when available.  So the fact that PhantonJS exists in Homebrew and in npm shows that it was either added before this policy was enacted, or that there is a specific reason why it doesn't work as well when pulled from npm.  Looking at the Homebrew package file, it includes a patch, so that might be the reason.  So without knowing any better, I would probably try the Homebrew version first, but ultimately it might not make a difference which one you use.